# How do I load dotenv in Typescript

Tags: mongodb, typescript, express

I'm trying to load .env environment variable using Typescript.

This is my `.env` and `app.ts` files

```
//.env

DB_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test
```

```js
// app.ts

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, config);
```

When I run `app.ts` using `ts-node src/app.ts` command, throwing this error

```sh
Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts:50:18 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(uris: string, callback: (err: MongoError) => void): Promise<typeof import("mongoose")>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(uris: string, options?: ConnectionOptions | undefined): Promise<typeof import("mongoose")>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

50 mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, config);
```

But when I add below if statement, it works well

```js
//app.ts
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

dotenv.config();

//Add this code
if (!process.env.DB_URL) {
  process.exit(1);
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, config);
```

```sh
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
Mongoose default connection is open to  mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test
```

I want to know why is this error not thrown in below code?

Comment: Can you put `console.log('DB_URL=' + process.env.DB_URL)` and  `console.log('config=' + config)` after `dotenv.config();` and give the output?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the error message, you can conclude that TypeScript expect the first parameter of `mongoose.connect()` to be a `string` but environment variables can be either `string` or `undefined`.

By adding the condition, you eliminate the possibility that `process.env.DB_URL` would be `undefined` when at the time you call `mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, config)`

If you are certain that it will never be `undefined`, you can use TypeScript [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL!, config);
```

**Tip:**

Instead of

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
...
dotenv.config();
```

You can do as the following

```
import 'dotenv/config'
```

This will make sure environment variables are set before the next `import` statements, so you would only have to do this only once at the main file of your app.

Comment: `import from 'dotenv/config'` supposed to be `import 'dotenv/config'`